# Insert HH:mm:ss from Android to MySql

Tags: android, mysql

I want to insert my current time into mysql but the result is only 00:00:00

This is my code :

```
String time;
SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
Calendar calendars = Calendar.getInstance();
time = dayFormat.format(calendars.getTime());
```

And the format in MySql is "time".

How to get fixed of this ?

Thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dayFormat.format(calendars.getTime());` returns the actual time in HH:mm:ss format, but with type StringBuffer. When you pass it to MySQL, the DB is expecting a java.sql.Date, and then it's storing the default date value (00:00:00).

One solution could be storing the date in the database with type `text` or trying to parse the StringBuffer before passing it to the DB.

Comment: So is there any solution ? I didn't need to use that currentTime data again. It just for report. I have tried to change it into String in mysql but returns null.

Comment: You have to possible solutions now in the answer (I've just edited it)